# What is this boolean algebra expression inverted?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I basically have this boolean algebra expression:

```
((xDir === 1 || xDir === -1) &&
 (yDir === 1 || yDir === -1))
```

What is the "inverse" of this? I tried using DeMorgan's thereoms but I don't think I did it properly. I ended up with something like:

```
(!(xDir === 1 && xDir === -1) &&
 !(yDir === 1 && yDir === -1))
```

What is the inverse equation?

Comment: Do you mean the negation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the programmatic notation,

```
!((a || b) && (c || d)) -> !(a || b) || !(c || d) -> (!a && !b) || (!c && !d)
```

There is no real benefit of effecting this transform as the final expression is more complex to evaluate and less readable.

Comment: One could use the fact that `xDir === 1 || xDir === -1` is equivalent to `xDir^2 === 1`, and similarly for `yDir`, to express the middle statement as `!(xDir^2 === 1) || !(yDir^2 === 1)`. This is relatively compact. (But then, one could also express the initial statement as just `(xDir^2-1)*(yDir^2-1)===0`.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: the question is not about efficient implementation (for which more information should be requested),it's about application of the De Morgran's laws.